# how to update a parameter (i.e. dropout rate or units) at each epoch within a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I am trying to add another parameter to Keras's implementation of deep learning architecture which changes at each or after a number of epochs.

Assume in new architecture (CNN, RNN, etc.), a parameter 'alpha1' is added, and I want to initialize it with a value for example 16,

Now, at the time of training, at each epoch, I want to update the alpha1.  Suppose, at each epoch, alpha1 = alpha1 * somevalue.

Since in keras/../recurrent.py, step(.) function where the computations are made is only called one time (not at every epoch), I could not add the
update of a parameter in here.
Is there any way of updating a parameter in keras model during training?

Comment: It may be done by custom layer, also I am not sure because the graph would be generated on that 'alpha1' value, as it is generated there may not be a way to update it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to loop the training as followed.

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
  model.fit(X=... , epochs=1)
  alpha1 = alpha1 * somevalue
```

Comment: Thank you @krenerd. alpha1 is a local variable here, but I want to update the alpha1 variable in keras/../recurrent.py.

Answer (score 0):

I think to can make a list of values for N epochs, then for each epoch you multiply by the values from the list (since you can easily count which epoch you are):

```
alpha = alpha * somevalue[epoch_i]
```